# How to deal with this error when build with Scons?

Tags: boost, scons

/usr/bin/ld: build/bsp_src/main.o: Undefined first referenced symbol «_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv»

//usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.54.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

[SConstruct file](http://pastebin.com/0fyue8aE)

I'm trying to build this project https://github.com/TTimo/es_core, and don't have enought expirience with scons

Comment: You add a new library to the linker inputs, the one that's named in the rest of the command line. Implicit/indirect dependencies are not ok (anymore? I think that has been a change about 3 years back)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the `SConstruct` file referenced in your question, you're not correctly linking in the boost_system library. You're doing it as follows:

```
env.Append( CCFLAGS = [ '-g', '-lboost_system', ] )
```

The `CCFLAGS` variable should be used to pass compilation flags to the Compiler. The `-l` flag should be passed to the Linker, not the Compiler. The correct way to do that in SCons is as follows:

```
env.Append( LIBS = ['boost_system'] )
```

Notice, I dont add the `-l` flag, as `SCons` does that for you in a platform-independent manner.

You may also have to define the path to the library, which is done as follows:

```
env.Append( LIBPATH = '/put/the/path/here' )
```

As with the `LIBS`, you dont need to add the `-L` flag to `LIBPATH`, as `SCons` will add it.

Here is a complete list of the [SCons Construction Variables](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html#app-variables).