# Scons 2.3.4 g++ link order

Tags: scons

I wrote a complicated scons script. But I found my program won't be compiled successful.
The error code is : "error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line"
I checked the compile progress. I found the g++ link order was changed.
I don't know by who and why?

So, did anyone meet this issue?

Comment: If you want to know whether anyone else has experienced the same problem, a Google search might help. If you want to know how to get a specific order of gcc options within SCons, please post a simple example of your current SConstruct, your current output (verbatim!) and which output you actually want. This will help other users to push you in the right direction.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901934/strange-linking-error-dso-missing-from-command-line#19905704 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700320/how-to-deal-with-this-error-when-build-with-scons